# How to check user is authenticated in second browser tab?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I used Identity authentication in my server side blazor application. I wrote sign out with redirect to login page, but faced the problem I can still use application if it is open in second browser tab.

For example: application is opened in tab1 and tab2. User log out in tab1 and then redirect to login page, but in tab2 can still use application. If refresh tab2 by F5 then redirect to login page.

Is there any simple solution for server side blazor application?

Comment: maybe need to use reverse ajax or sse .

Comment: What do you think about setting additional cookie and check value with $(document).click function? Is it safe?

Comment: @mah454 Is there any way to notify [Authorize] attribute that specific user is currently signed out?